# The screen freezes while moving files/apps across screens with remote session?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, freeze

I have a Laptop(`i7 and 2GB NVIDIA graphic card`) with an extended monitor(`27 inches`). When working remotely, whenever I'm dragging some apps like file explorer/chrome to another screen, the screen seems to freeze and respond after `~20-30` seconds, which is a huge lag. When working locally, everything is just smooth.

For the system setup, I have a good stable internet connection `~100Mbps`, and all other aspects of resources are pretty good. Anything I'm missing here? Something doesn't fit right for my case?

What can be the suspect here as I already eliminated the obvious ones? Any hint/idea in the right direction will do!

Laptop details:

```
processor
11th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 Processor (12MB Cache, up to 4.7 GHz)

Windows 10 Home Single Language, English

videocard
NVIDIA® GeForce® MX350 with 2GB GDDR5 graphics memory

memory
8GB, 1x8GB, DDR4, 3200MHz

harddrive
512GB M.2 PCIe NVMe Solid State Drive
```

Remote session details:

I'm using multi-screen RDP, that is my remote session is spread across both the screens i.e one laptop screen and an external monitor. I'm using Citrix receiver for remote connection.

FURTHER UPDATES FROM ME:

The problem statement reduces to the point that all dragging/moving is working fine, just the laptop screen is not reflecting the change at that exact moment, pressing Alt+Tab at that moment is the hack I found, pressing it is refreshing the screen all of a sudden, but it is a temporary solution as well as it is not very convenient to press it whenever I move/drag files across the screens

Comment: Are you using the latest NVIDIA driver [version 461.72](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/170887/en-us)?

Comment: Try forcing your graphics drivers to reload (ctrl + Shift + Windows Key + B)

Comment: @harrymc Driver version is showing 451.67 for me

Comment: I'll update it and check!

Comment: 451.67 is also the one I'm using, and it seems very stable. Try version 461.72, but have 451.67 ready in case of degradation.

Comment: @harrymc No luck with 461.72, actually the remote NVIDIA driver version is 442.06, so do downgrading the version could help in this case?

Comment: Try on the remote one the versions of 451.67 an 461.72. If none helps, maybe it isn't the NVIDIA driver the cause.

Comment: @harrymc One small progress, the screen which is freezing is the one who is set as main screen. Just switched the main screen and altogether the freezing/lagging is happening on the other screen

Comment: Are the two screens used by RDP? Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1628301/edit) your post with an exact description of how you are using them.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for pointing it out, added!

Comment: I would initially run: `wpr -start DesktopComposition -start Video -start CPU` from an admin prompt.  Then reproduce it and run `wpr -stop C:\hang.etl`.  Once done, take a look at the trace with Windows Performance Analyzer which you can get from the Store or by downloading the SDK.

Comment: Check if [this post](https://www.beringer.net/beringerblog/quick-guide-lag-free-remote-desktop-experience/) helps.

Comment: The link above counseled to disable pointer shadow and removing some of the settings under “Experience”.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried unchecking options under Experience but no luck. It does not look like a case of the slow mouse(the above link) either

Comment: @HelpingHand your idea sounds quite good, but neither I have experience of analyzing the trace nor the remote machine will allow any sort of these things to execute in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a Windows bug for this particular configuration:

```
XenDesktop 7.15 LTSR CU1 and CU4 Windows 10 2016 LTSB
Citrix Receiver 4.9 LTSR CU5/CU6 (6001) Windows 10 2019 LTSC
Graphics card: Intel UHD Graphics 620/630 (or) Intel HD graphics 4000
```

Problem Cause:

```
D3D11 rendering API's doesn't work as expected with Intel 620/630 GPU's.
```

Citrix has a work around for this which is working in my case: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX261911

PS: special thanks to [@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) for sticking around so long, sometimes we just need someone to believe that our issues are genuine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking for an update for your remote desktop client and for your graphics card. If you can, try a different remote desktop client and see if the same thing happens.

Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of manipulations that might help:

1. If your primary monitor is on the right, try switching it to the left.
2. Go to *Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab >
   Performance Settings > Visual Effects tab* and disable all effects.
3. Run `gpedit.msc`, navigate to
   *Computer configuration\Admin Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client*, and ensure that "Turn Off UDP On Client" is enabled.
4. On the **server** side, use `gpedit` to go to
   *Computer configuration\Admin Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment*, and ensure that
   "Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections" is disabled.